# Can't add column to datagridview programmatically in visual basic.net using method in class

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

i want to ask something about datagridview in visual basic

i have 1 form name 'form1' and 1 class name 'test' in my project, within the class there is 1 method 'addColumn()'.

i want to add column to datagridview programmatically, when i add directly to form1 from method form1_load, it's success. the code like this

---

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("01", 1)
```

But when i add the column via method from class test,

Dim obj As test

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    obj.addColumns(DataGridView1)
End Sub
```

i got error this

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

code in class test like this

```
Public Function addColumns(ByVal dgv As DataGridView)
    dgv.Columns.Add("01", 1)
End Function
```

What wrong with my code?, there are any way to solve this error.
Please help me...

Comment: that expeption is because obj is null, how is obj declared?

Comment: now i know my mistake, i forgot to add statement 'New' when declare object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not declaring a New test object, hence the error.

```
Dim obj As New test
```

Or make the function a `Shared Function`

```
Public Shared Function addColumns(ByVal dgv As DataGridView)
  dgv.Columns.Add("01", 1)
End Function
```

Then no need to declare any obj object. Use the function directly.

```
test.addColumns(DataGridView1)
```

Comment: Oh yeah, i am forgot to add 'New' statement in my declaration object. Thanks a lot for your response

Answer (score 0):

change `Dim obj As test` to

```
Dim obj  as New test
```

You only declared your obj but not initialized. since obj  is null when you call `addColumns` method you will receive

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: i forgot to add 'new' statement in my code, Thanks for your answer